# Redux store doesn't update component props

Tags: redux, react-native

I'm trying to call a API from my store to update the state of a component, here getting the price of a crypto-curency.

I use a clone of my state in return (nextState here) and the log of nextState is well fill with goods price, but my component get only the initialState.

Here the code :

My component

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Bitcoin extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
    }
    }

componentDidMount() {
    const action = { type: 'PRICES', value: this.state.cryptos}
    this.props.dispatch(action)
    console.log(this.props.cryptos)
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Component did Update : ")
    console.log(this.props.cryptos)
}

  render() {
return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Bitcoin !</Text>
        <Text> {this.props.cryptos[0].price} </Text>
    </View>
)
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
title: {
    marginTop: wp("10%")
},
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    cryptos: state.Crypto.cryptos
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatch: (action) => { dispatch(action) }
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Bitcoin)
```

My Reducer :

```
const initialState = {  cryptos: [
                    {
                        title: "Bitcoin",
                        id: "BTC",
                        price: 0
                    }, {
                        title: "Ethereum",
                        id: "ETH",
                        price: 0
                    }, {
                        title: "Ripple",
                        id: "XRP",
                        price: 0
                    }], toast: 0}

function Crypto(state = initialState, action) {
    let nextState
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'PRICES':
        nextState = {...state}
        fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,BTC,XRP&tsyms=EUR&api_key=c3b60840403013f86c45f2ee97571ffdf60072fafff5c133ed587d91088451b6')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            nextState.cryptos[0].price = responseJson.BTC.EUR.toString()
            nextState.cryptos[1].price = responseJson.ETH.EUR.toString()
            nextState.cryptos[2].price = responseJson.XRP.EUR.toString()
            console.log("NextState :");
            console.log(nextState.cryptos);
            return nextState
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
        return nextState
    case 'TOAST':
        nextState = {...state}
    default:
        return state
    }
}

export default Crypto
```

Comment: Your current approach goes against redux. Reducer function must be pure function. No side effects allowed here. You should place network related code to the component itself or to the action creator using say thunk middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.
I guess you are new to Redux workflow. So here it is.

Actions describe an action. The reducer receive the action and specify how the store is changing.

Action must be plain javascript object. And reducer functions must be [pure](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/) !

Here what is forbidden to do inside reducers :

```
  Mutate its arguments;
  Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
  Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().
```

In your example, by calling fetch. You're making an API Call.

I invite you to read this guide to know more about : How to introduce API call and asynchronous into your redux app. (https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)